# Spread images based on random numbers

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I want to spread my images throughout the page based on the X and Y values the user gives into the plugin. Currently, it takes the WHOLE set of images and places it as a bar on the latest two coordinates I get. But I want the images to be spread randomly over the area the user defines.

```
flickrJSONParse: function (response) {
            $.each(response, function (item, i) {
                $.each(i.photo, function (photoItem, ItemI) {
                    var URL = "http://farm" + ItemI.farm + ".staticflickr.com/" + ItemI.server + "/" + ItemI.id + "_" + ItemI.secret + "_b.jpg";
                    var generated = $selector.append("<div class='item'><img class='image' src=" + URL + " alt=" + ItemI.title + " />" + "<a href='#' class='overlay'><h3 class='title'>" + ItemI.title + "</h3></a>" + "</div>");
                    generated.css({
                        position: "absolute",
                        left: Math.floor(Math.random()*(settings.Xmax-settings.Xmin+1)+settings.Xmin),
                        top: Math.floor(Math.random()*(settings.Ymax-settings.Ymin+1)+settings.Ymin)
                    })
                });
            });
        }
```

Above is my code, and below is my CSS:

```
html, body, *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
html{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1em;
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.image{
    margin: 0;
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
}
.image:after{
    clear: both;
}
.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    display: none;
}
.overlay .title{
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
.item:hover .overlay{
    display: block;
}
```

This is the jsFiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uw6Pv/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `.append()` returns the original object, not the one you append to it. So maybe something like `generated.find('#'+newItemId).css(/*css stuff*/);` where newItemId is the `id` attribute of the `item` you just inserted.

Comment: But, I would want to randomize **every** image, not the latest?

Comment: Yes, precisely that! Thank you! Could I also make a kind of setting that checks whether they overlap and then makes more space?

Comment: You would have to change how you are doing the random placement, but I'm sure that would be possible.